# OpenStack FWaaS extension

Tags: firewall, openstack

According to the [OpenStack API documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-network/2.0/content/fwaas_ext.html), OpenStack now provides APIs to manage and deploy firewalls to protect the networks.

The information available for the firewalls via the APIs seems very limited. For example, you could create a firewall with a policy that is comprised of a set of rules. But how could you define where this firewall is located, which subnets are separated by it, which packets does it apply it's rules on?

Any explanations on how this works, or referenecs to more descriptive documentation on the matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We found the deployment instructions and CLI and REST examples in this document: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Neutron/FWaaS/HowToInstall#REST_calls_using_curl:

The policy (and therefore rules) in FWaaS are all applied to all of the tenant's routers.

A year after this question is asked we have LBaaS and VPNaaS in the API documentation but no sign of the FWaaS API.

It works in Icehouse and Juno so still supported.